# Nuxt.js first loading

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I understood it was `ssr` when I first loaded the Nuxt.js. But I don't understand how loading a page with `ssr` and using it with `csr` works.
Also, I wonder if asyncData works only when it is operated by `csr`. How does the Nuxt.js work?

Comment: When you referred to csr what you mean? It's not clear what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between SSR (Server side rendered) and CSR (Client side rendered) is, that with SSR your servers response to the browser is the HTML of your page that is ready to be rendered, while for CSR the browser just gets an empty document with links to your Javascript.

Getting a server generated page means that your browser will start rendering the HTML from your server without having to wait for **all the JavaScript** to be downloaded and executed.

Nuxt.js is using genrating a SSR page just for the first load (which speeds up to initial load time, and has some more advantages). Once all the Javascript is loaded, Nuxt.js mounts the original Vue app, which will make everything reactive, apply the routing etc.

Comment: Thank you. I have a question, but if I take more than a second to load all Javascripts and route them in, does it work with SSR?